# Filling up column of text file with random data using bash

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have a file with the format

```
<string> <string> <string>
..
..
```

I am trying to replace the third column string with random data using sed. The third column string length is fixed and is 48 digits

I was able to fix up a solution using read

```
while read a b c; do
    echo $a $b $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-1' | fold -w 48 | head -n 1)
done < input > output
```

However the loop takes too long too process. How can I do this with sed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-1'` is a horribly slow way to get random numbers - you're discarding a lot of data just because it doesn't parse to an ASCII number.

You could use `od` or `hexdump` to convert the data to numbers, instead, maybe `awk` to replace the third field:

```
$ awk -v cmd="od -t u2 -A n /dev/urandom | tr -d ' \n' | fold -w 48" '{cmd | getline a; $3=a}1' foo
a b 544404963198532458179603539139474299576034345258
a b 288743886427692659230387417952036728563243415446
a b 862132599821016414678116482868514114597223157825
a b 033164829235119519053106724136729063192651002644
a b 344594724128550250448115260033862902855932105599
a b 312488113115218631189450762993316672549312384472
a b 536218132619476215470461793189974621744028599402
a b 312943765306550325469516346331872556359574159859
a b 530561655804530239462031928466172515137971221356
a b 295271911741933346066441964722122556255551414840
```

`od -t u2 -A n /dev/urandom | tr -d ' \n' | fold -w 48` converts the random data into two-byte `unsigned int`s, then we use `tr` to remove the spaces from `od`'s  output.

`awk` is very nice for column-based text processing. The [`<command> | getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe) method allows you to run the `<command>` *once* and then read its output for the duration of the `awk` command.

A simpler way than coercing `od` output to the required format is to use `hexdump`:

```
hexdump -e '"%u"' /dev/urandom | fold -w 48
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the perl [Bytes::Random::Secure](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Bytes-Random-Secure-0.29/lib/Bytes/Random/Secure.pm) module:

```
$ perl -MBytes::Random::Secure=random_bytes_hex -alne '
  print join " ", @F[1..2], random_bytes_hex(24)
' file
<string> <string> 56fe375ade090e9838c13b5bbb799c2fac26d42da3f01691
<string> <string> 8bf748fb4d372e701af5ae0075a9de58c8ce3b05210c24bd
<string> <string> 345c58a5983e7bade8fed0311267daeea9ed314b1efe33d1
```

The module is available in Ubuntu via package `libbytes-random-secure-perl`