# replace entire column in a file with random String

Tags: command-line, text-processing

What is the easiest way to replace a column in a file?
basically, my `file.txt` has 3 columns separated by `,`.

How can I change the second column with a bash script?

```
SveUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,64BzZdqrYY7Tx8sbj5tmEW,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,gTdmvjmahIOoyzmrttVMvTc1ER0bt,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,LzLtoEg18E1brm66dPjcHZfpI107nn4h,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
7cjW5DZlXw1LYzVugbVyqfxRX,i7B4Q9w8h5anmMW87DfIBEm0AuNjbLGq,XttE1In9eZQ8puJVUriuNvx2AJAxviGf
XiLE8r9AMqy5YZQ9BbIS6m559,ToT2wbQdpNNySPxP1Tgz1,DssiszVBa05pbVDSOXNRaFXRxw0eZKHf
Sygrl5287BViOn0uQ9uCYipB1,TEYnXl6APWGbm9ckLCcHFUJzk7qS8JXH,sD2O46sbh1yVIluoyn6Zm2OKXYe05vV9
Qi6DxJ96M0hxNe4cgux3iJ1aS,LK3GHTpuo9kbmK9McRN4sFRQTGh2DU8J,wk2eF3f9xk5HowLzDIL3hCCNSmx8Uwi8
ZIX7qp5IIPekA0kzBdFR4IUQZ,9m9lEjfiotQ97s3uVN8EEP7Y1JmpgAk7,99ilfJWoJEBsKOfYI3buFfher07OCz6Y
```

**Update**
replace with another string in a variable. let's say `var=new-sting`.

Actually, I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
sed "s/,[^,]*/,$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)/" file.txt
```

But it is not working as expected. I am having the same string over and over.

Comment: Will it be the same replacement string for every line?

Comment: @ByteCommander yes, in my script I will handle the variable

Comment: So you want to process just one line, then do some application logic to update the replacement variable and then process the next line? Otherwise there are tools to process the whole file at once.

Comment: @ByteCommander I want to replace by another random string. It can be done in one line

Comment: That was not the question. Can I process the whole file at once, replacing the middle column of all lines with the exactly same string, or do we have to process it line by line, because you need to update the replacement variable after each line somehow?

Comment: If you want to replace with a *different* random string each line, I'd suggest using something like perl's [Bytes::Random::Secure module](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Bytes-Random-Secure-0.29/lib/Bytes/Random/Secure.pm) - see for example [Filling up column of text file with random data using bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857518/filling-up-column-of-text-file-with-random-data-using-bash/857666#857666)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `file.txt` contains lines of text that are divided into three columns with commas and that there are no additional commas anywhere, so each line has exactly two of them:

```
replacement="my string"
sed "s/,.*,/,$replacement,/" file.txt
```

Output:

```
SveUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,my string,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,my string,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,my string,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
7cjW5DZlXw1LYzVugbVyqfxRX,my string,XttE1In9eZQ8puJVUriuNvx2AJAxviGf
XiLE8r9AMqy5YZQ9BbIS6m559,my string,DssiszVBa05pbVDSOXNRaFXRxw0eZKHf
Sygrl5287BViOn0uQ9uCYipB1,my string,sD2O46sbh1yVIluoyn6Zm2OKXYe05vV9
Qi6DxJ96M0hxNe4cgux3iJ1aS,my string,wk2eF3f9xk5HowLzDIL3hCCNSmx8Uwi8
ZIX7qp5IIPekA0kzBdFR4IUQZ,my string,99ilfJWoJEBsKOfYI3buFfher07OCz6Y
```

This will process all lines at once and replace the middle column with the same value each time. The changed content will be printed to the terminal by default, if you want to modify `file.txt` in place instead, write `sed -i` instead of plain `sed`.

---

If you need to update the replacement variable for each line anyhow (here a new random string for each line), you can loop over the lines like this:

```
while read line ; do
    replacement="random number $RANDOM"
    sed "s/,.*,/,$replacement,/" <<< "$line"
done < file.txt
```

Example output:

```
SveUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,random number 27584,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,random number 2959,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,random number 5463,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
7cjW5DZlXw1LYzVugbVyqfxRX,random number 12889,XttE1In9eZQ8puJVUriuNvx2AJAxviGf
XiLE8r9AMqy5YZQ9BbIS6m559,random number 3754,DssiszVBa05pbVDSOXNRaFXRxw0eZKHf
Sygrl5287BViOn0uQ9uCYipB1,random number 25375,sD2O46sbh1yVIluoyn6Zm2OKXYe05vV9
Qi6DxJ96M0hxNe4cgux3iJ1aS,random number 5284,wk2eF3f9xk5HowLzDIL3hCCNSmx8Uwi8
```

It's probably the easiest way to put this code snippet into a script file and then you ran redirect its output to a separate new file (not the original file from which you read!) like this:

```
bash my-replacement-script.sh > new-file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest an approach based on the perl [Bytes::Random::Secure module](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Bytes-Random-Secure-0.29/lib/Bytes/Random/Secure.pm), based on [Filling up column of text file with random data using bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/857666/178692) modified to use your desired mix of upper and lower case letters and decimal digits:

```
perl -MBytes::Random::Secure=random_string_from -F, -ane '
  BEGIN{$chars = join "", ("a".."z","A".."Z",0..9)}
  $F[1] = random_string_from($chars, 32);
  print join ",", @F
' file
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use your `/dev/urandom` pipeline, one way to do that without external looping would be using a FIFO with awk's `getline` function:

1. make the FIFO `$ mkfifo _fifo`
2. execute your command, streaming its output to the FIFO

   ```
   $ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 > _fifo &
   ```

   or (eliminating the [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

   ```
   $ tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 32 > _fifo &
   ```
3. get lines from the FIFO and substitute them in to the lines of the target file

   ```
   $ awk '{getline $2 < "_fifo"} 1' FS=, OFS=, file
   ```
4. remove the FIFO

   ```
   rm _fifo
   ```

Testing:

```
$ mkfifo _fifo
$ tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 32 > _fifo &
[1] 5815
$ awk '{getline $2 < "_fifo"} 1' FS=, OFS=, file
SveUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,hpqBxCOYIj7eQ9MgbPNG69SY3X3iAJ7A,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,ACU1hyR8zGRfDMeUk4a6TFVcQvUAtZog,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,dkeKUnMYZepGcGMgdQc9IORa77Vtwr7w,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
7cjW5DZlXw1LYzVugbVyqfxRX,UMjkPZAB3ElpOnXWnsQe9w1v0h6HMLPs,XttE1In9eZQ8puJVUriuNvx2AJAxviGf
XiLE8r9AMqy5YZQ9BbIS6m559,iz5tavnYqajwTokPCM4HJIsZlIloLcVy,DssiszVBa05pbVDSOXNRaFXRxw0eZKHf
Sygrl5287BViOn0uQ9uCYipB1,RHPFMgKoIGojvM6aTwb43lH4BAr8Jh5Y,sD2O46sbh1yVIluoyn6Zm2OKXYe05vV9
Qi6DxJ96M0hxNe4cgux3iJ1aS,fqTsEPr3PIPqIWPrb2uIl47QjXlSt3gL,wk2eF3f9xk5HowLzDIL3hCCNSmx8Uwi8
ZIX7qp5IIPekA0kzBdFR4IUQZ,uAFKvX5z2ik2i1AKh3wYp503xpNy8dxA,99ilfJWoJEBsKOfYI3buFfher07OCz6Y
rm _fifo
[1]+  Broken pipe             cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 > _fifo
```

With GNU awk, you can do the equivalent internally using `getline` with a *co-process*:

```
$ gawk '{"tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 32" |& getline $2} 1' FS=, OFS=, file 
SveUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,hKOYDf6lgEtVwzJvCl34eYu22m5bZ11e,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,bV9m4OgbTzDTJQanhS3BTmxr5gUcouDy,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,r9850TtXPJsLLNMupiwSPsqx7ovtb5ph,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
7cjW5DZlXw1LYzVugbVyqfxRX,aRRVAecWxeTtt3WX36MIoFlMCvDcFb3a,XttE1In9eZQ8puJVUriuNvx2AJAxviGf
XiLE8r9AMqy5YZQ9BbIS6m559,BeCoCV4kMb8FUt6Y3RFxolI2CKqzbeuO,DssiszVBa05pbVDSOXNRaFXRxw0eZKHf
Sygrl5287BViOn0uQ9uCYipB1,WZ0hSxurp22dCdhV12Gjcms6rdx8hjM2,sD2O46sbh1yVIluoyn6Zm2OKXYe05vV9
Qi6DxJ96M0hxNe4cgux3iJ1aS,ujxdLQZo1vkCZnkUej6pLjZxVmN7XiTE,wk2eF3f9xk5HowLzDIL3hCCNSmx8Uwi8
ZIX7qp5IIPekA0kzBdFR4IUQZ,qxp3dwltN5Mxfece27Zvq2NqbjPlF358,99ilfJWoJEBsKOfYI3buFfher07OCz6Y
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v var="mystring" -F, 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$2 = var; print}'
```

- `-v`: create a variable named `var` which contains the string "mystring"
- `-F,`: use `,` as field separator
- `BEGIN {OFS = FS}` set output field separator equal to field separator to keep the separator (comma) after replacement
- `{$2 = var; print}` replace the field 2 (column 2)  with `var` content; then print.

You can also change `-v var="mystring"` with something like `-v var="$variable"` which `$variable` is an variable in your environment.

---

Here is an example:

```
veUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,64BzZdqrYY7Tx8sbj5tmEW,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,gTdmvjmahIOoyzmrttVMvTc1ER0bt,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,LzLtoEg18E1brm66dPjcHZfpI107nn4h,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
```

let's run the  command:

```
$ awk -v var="HERE-IS-MY-STRING" -F, 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$2 = var; print}' file.tx

veUJW24ibppfePgYeYHz7fC0,HERE-IS-MY-STRING,yL6mCP0Do28k4EoTZUfKfqNYiIhGxxkA
xyRG8Da6kY35xeIT492Lul7xu,HERE-IS-MY-STRING,ne6RIM2TeMQAax1GgzL7FeDrnQyHPH1i
sxTf13KlAnjtXodJouQ9V6m5b,HERE-IS-MY-STRING,GUnApYwwDCZxWGZtzKzTU6sJRgHlUUfQ
```